# dynamic pages with php according to a var?

Tags: php

I am using php to create url shorten website.

Within that script I am using a function that will randomly pick a value of 6 characters between a-z, A-Z, and 0-9. Now the function is storing its value in a var called `$value`. This value will be stored in mysql database.

I want to make php create a dynamic url in this form `www.mysite.com/$value` according to the value of my var. Also within this new page I want to use server side include to display the new page contents. 
How can I get to this approach?

I am new to php and I am not familiar with all of its functions, I am not even sure if I can do something like that. Any Ideas ?

Comment: so get the value from the url and display the contents - where is the problem?

Comment: no the value from the var to the url

Comment: @Dagon I think the OP simply does not know how to route such a dynamic URL to a single script. Norman's answer is a good start. But it's not possible using PHP alone; you'll need to configure your Web server too.

Comment: is there a simpler way than using .httpacces ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. You'd want to route all requests to a particular file (such as router.php or index.php) and .htaccess allows exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a router?
http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/